# Integration of odd and even functions. Where is a flaw in my proof?

Tags: calculus, integration, even-and-odd-functions

If the function $f$ has the property   $f(a+x) = -f(a-x)$ $\forall x$, where *a* is a constant, then

$$\int_{(a-2)}^{(a+2)} f(x)dx = 0$$.

---

I have to deside whether this statement is true or false, and to give a proof.
I understand that here $f$ is an odd function hence the statement is true, however while prooving it got the following results:

[[image]

Which shows the opposite (that f is an even function). Where did I made a mistake? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm sorry I don't have the fancy sign for the defined integral, I hope you understand what my equation looks like from the pinned photo.

Comment: On the third line of your proof you made the u sub u=-x however you forgot to multiply the integral by u' = -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from your second to your third line, there's a missing minus sign.

When you change $\int_0^2 f(x+a) dx$ to $\int_0^{-2} f(-x+a) dx$, you're really doing a substitution $u=-x$ (and then renaming $u$ as $x$, which is fine). This changes your limits of integration from $0..2$ to $0..-2$, but it also changes the $dx$ to $-du$, so an extra minus sign should appear to account for that. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful.